# What is the requirement for fire fighting equipment on board a passenger flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, fire, icao-sarps

What is the legal requirement regarding fire fighting equipment on a passenger flight, e.g. fire extinguishers and fire hoods? I imagine that the number is proportional to the airplane's max capacity.

<sub>I'd prefer ICAO since it applies internationally, but if there is none, a FAA reference would be a good as well.</sub>

Comment: Gas masks? Do you mean oxygen masks? Or fire hoods?

Comment: @RonBeyer I mean hoods. Edited.

Comment: Aren't they published and can be readily googled?

Comment: @Koyovis Published and "easily googled" information are still valid questions, just makes it easier to answer...

Comment: There are also mandatory extinguishers for engines /APU and cargo holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this tagged  both FAA and ICAO but for the FAA thats governed under

> **[§ 121.309 Emergency equipment.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/121.309)**
>
> (c)Hand fire extinguishers for crew, passenger, cargo, and galley
>   compartments. Hand fire extinguishers of an approved type must be
>   provided for use in crew, passenger, cargo, and galley compartments in
>   accordance with the following:
>
> (1) The type and quantity of extinguishing agent must be suitable for
>   the kinds of fires likely to occur in the compartment where the
>   extinguisher is intended to be used and, for passenger compartments,
>   must be designed to minimize the hazard of toxic gas concentrations.
>
> (2)Cargo compartments. At least one hand fire extinguisher must be
>   conveniently located for use in each class E cargo compartment that is
>   accessible to crewmembers during flight.
>
> (3)Galley compartments. At least one hand fire extinguisher must be
>   conveniently located for use in each galley located in a compartment
>   other than a passenger, cargo, or crew compartment.
>
> (4)Flightcrew compartment. At least one hand fire extinguisher must be
>   conveniently located on the flight deck for use by the flightcrew.
>
> (5)Passenger compartments. Hand fire extinguishers for use in
>   passenger compartments must be conveniently located and, when two or
>   more are required, uniformly distributed throughout each compartment.
>   Hand fire extinguishers shall be provided in passenger compartments as
>   follows:
>
> (i) For airplanes having passenger se ats accommodating more than 6
>   but fewer than 31 passengers, at least one.
>
> (ii) For airplanes having passenger se ats accommodating more than 30
>   but fewer than 61 passengers, at least two.
>
> (iii) For airplanes having passenger se ats accommodating more than 60
>   passengers, there must be at least the following number of hand fire
>   extinguishers:
>
> **Minimum Number of Hand Fire Extinguishers Passenger seating
>   accommodations:**
>
> 61 through 200:   3
>
> 201 through 300:  4
>
> 301 through 400:  5
>
> 401 through 500:  6
>
> 501 through 600:  7
>
> 601 or more:  8
>
> (6) Notwithstanding
>   the requirement for uniform distribution of hand fire extinguishers as
>   prescribed in paragraph (c)(5) of this section, for those cases where
>   a galley is located in a passenger compartment, at least one hand fire
>   extinguisher must be conveniently located and easily accessible for
>   use in the galley.
>
> (7) At least two of the required hand fire extinguisher installed in
>   passenger-carrying airplanes must contain Halon 1211
>   (bromochlorofluoromethane) or equivalent as the extinguishing agent.
>   At least one hand fire extinguisher in the passenger compartment must
>   contain Halon 1211 or equivalent.

You may also find some [pertinent info here](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/cabin_safety/media/CabinSafetyIndex.pdf).

Comment: In paragraph no. 1 you mentioned that the type of agent must be suitable to minimize the hazard of toxic gas concentration , at the same time you recommend using hallon gas extinguisher and everyone knows that it is toxic and affects human health why not replace with alternatives of hall9n such as FM200 or etc.

Comment: @Saidasad These are not my recommendations they are those of the FAA please see included links.